# Collection? Dictionary? List?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j's manual does a very good job at explaining the meaning of the terms Node, Relationship, Label and a few others.

However, the **real** vocabulary of Cypher seems to include quite a few elusive terms, as well.

For instance, clause 3.3.15.1 of the manual says "Lists and paths are key concepts in Cypher". Fine, but what is a List in Cypher? I have all but given up trying to find a definition of that "key concept".

Similarly, the Cypher Reference Card mentions that "Cypher also supports maps and collections". Elsewhere, one can find that Cypher also "works with dictionaries".

Needless to say, I am in the dark as to how to spot and/or use those in Cypher.

Would really appreciate some illustrations.

Thanks.

Comment: Please upvote answers that you found useful. Also, if some of them provide a satisfactory answer your question, mark the best one as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia :

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type) : a list (or sequence, collection) is a data type that represents a countable number of ordered values.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type) : a map (or dictionnary) is a data type composed of a collection of (key, value) pairs.

And in Cypher :

- this is a **list** : `RETURN ['Benoit', 'Simard'] AS list`
- this is a **map** : `RETURN { firstname:'Benoit', lastname:'Simard'} AS map`

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide some rationale/use cases for these types specifically in Cypher?

Comment: Also, are lists and maps Collections?

Answer (score 0):

The docs has a section on [Composite types](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/values/#composite-types):

> 3.2.1.3. Composite types
>
> - ✓ Can be returned from Cypher queries
> - ✓ Can be used as parameters
> - ❏ Cannot be stored as properties
> - ✓ Can be constructed with Cypher literals
>
> Composite types comprise:
>
> - **Lists** are heterogeneous, ordered collections of values, each of which has any property, structural or composite type.
> - **Maps** are heterogeneous, unordered collections of (key, value) pairs, where:
>
>   - the key is a String
>   - the value has any property, structural or composite type

You might also be interested in the development of openCypher. One of the goals of the [openCypher project](http://www.opencypher.org/) is to define the concepts of the Cypher language. As stated on its homepage:

> The openCypher project aims to deliver a full and open specification of the industry’s most widely adopted graph database query language: Cypher.

Currently, openCypher is a work-in-progress. It has a [draft document on the Property Graph Model](https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/blob/master/docs/property-graph-model.adoc), which itself does not discuss lists/maps in detail, but refers the [CIP2015-06-16 - Public Type System and Type Annotations](https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/blob/master/cip/1.accepted/CIP2015-09-16-public-type-system-type-annotation.adoc#types-and-type-literal-syntax) document, which is an accepted [Cypher Improvement Proposal](https://www.opencypher.org/cips). It has a section on "Container Types", which defines how lists and maps work in Cypher.

I have not seen the term "dictionary" in the core Neo4j docs. It could be mentioned around drivers though, as some languages, e.g. Python, use this term for maps.

(Disclaimer: I am a regular participant at the [openCypher Implementers Group](http://www.opencypher.org/ocig) meetings.)

Comment: I stumbled upon "Dictionary" in the paper Graph Processing with Neo4j by Julian M. Kunkel. Not in the core docs, which is exactly my problem with Neo4j's documentation!

Comment: If you [search for "dictionary"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22dictionary%22+site%3Aneo4j.com%2Fdocs%2F) in the Neo4j docs, it only occurs for client drivers and in the context of "dictionary order" (a.k.a. [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)). So the core docs never use `dictionary` in lieu of `map` when talking about Cypher.

Comment: The [Graph Processing with Neo4j](https://wr.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/_media/teaching/wintersemester_2016_2017/bd-8-neo4j.pdf) lecture did not use this official term for maps -- however, this does not cause a serious ambiguity as dictionary is a well-known synonym for maps.

Comment: The lecture even starts with a disclaimer: "Big Data software is constantly updated, code samples may be outdated". The same goes for concepts: a lot of concepts have multiple names, while some names might refer to multiple concepts. To get an example from this lecture, CQL usually refers to the _Cassandra Query Language_ and is not recommended to be used for Cypher. In general, concepts with multiple definitions are common not just in big data applications, but also in computer science.